# html + css text-decoration

Tags: html, css

Below is the code in which I tried using text-decoration:none. However, text is always underlined.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .search, .search_b1, .search_b2{
     display: block;
     color: #000;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    .search_b1:hover {
     color: red;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="left"> 
     <a href = "#">
      <span class="search"> 
       <span class="search_b1">Text text</span> 
       <span class="search_b2">Text text</span> 
      </span> 
     </a>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You set the span element to a block element.

Block elements can not have `text-decoration`. Only inline elements can.

Comment: I think you meant border-bottom: none; on this particular case.

Comment: note that the `border-bottom` trick doesn't work if the text wraps to a new line, unfortunately.

Comment: or just do: a { text-decoration: none; }

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the text-decoration to the anchor elements.

Comment: As I said on the other comment (sorry, I read that answer first), that can be achieved using: a { text-decoration: none; }